# Check programmatically whether multiple Worksheets are selected (CTRL+Click)

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

e.g. a user selects multiple worksheets in a workbook using CTRL+Click. How can I determine which worksheets are selected and which not? I was playing around with that but I couldn't find any useful property to check.

```
            Excel.Sheets abc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets;

            foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in abc)
            {
                if (sheet.EnableSelection != Excel.XlEnableSelection.xlNoSelection)
                {

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggeling around for almost 2 hours. But shortly after I posted this question I found a solution. The **ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets** delivers what I was looking for.

```
            Excel.Sheets abc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets;

            foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in abc)
            {
                string asdf = sheet.Name;
            }
```

I haven't knwon the **ActiveWindow** before.
Still hoping this is useful for someone else, too.